# How to convert a QVector to another with different types

Tags: c++, qt, c++17, qvector

How do I write a simple function (in C++ 17) that can get one QVector **of any type**, and returns a new one with converted values **of any other type**. For example:

```cpp
auto my_function(auto in, auto f) 
{
    // ... body of function
}

// Usage:

auto my_lambda = [] (int x) { return QString::number(x); }
QVector<int> in_vector = {1,2,3};
QVector<QString> res = my_func(in_vector, my_lambda);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let it be something like this

```
template<typename F>
auto my_map(const auto &data, F f)
{
    using ReturnType = std::invoke_result_t<F, decltype(data.at(0))>;
    QVector<ReturnType> res(data.size());
    std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), res.begin(), f);
    return res;
}
```

It works for non-empty vectors quite well.

***UPD:*** Yet another working variant:

```
auto my_map(const auto &data, auto f)
{
    using ReturnType = decltype(f(data.at(0)));
    QVector<ReturnType> res(data.size());
    std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), res.begin(), f);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: probably `invoke_result_t` is morecorrect or you have to strip possible references (just to be safe)?

Comment: it is, for the sake of greater safety

Answer (score 2):

You're literally describing [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), which actually works with Qt containers  (or any range-compatible containers).

If you *must* have exactly that signature, your function may act as an adapter for it. Because `auto` return type can be deduced only if you have a proper `return` and you still have to return SOME defined object, it's more prudent to use trailing type declaration, e.g. something like:

```
auto my_function(auto in, auto f) 
       -> QVector<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(f(*in.begin()))>>
{
    // do your own loop or use std::transform
}
```

PS. I'm just not a fan of hiding return type in function code if that's a public interface. Ofc you can declare type inside of body instead, see Alex's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77925382/2742717).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a vector of `QVariant`? Something like `QVector<QVariant> myVector`, and `myVector.at(0).toInt()` or `myVector.at(0).toString()` when you need to access the data.

Comment: No, I do not need a vector of QStrings, it was just an example of the functions using.

Comment: QVector <Qvariant> myVector;And then jse it like in my response

Comment: I've understood you, but it can't help me, for example I need QVector<double> transfrom to QVector<uint> with some modifications law, and QVector<QVariant> will do nothing on it.